# Liferay integration with OpenAM and OpenDJ

Tags: ldap, liferay, openam, opensso, opendj

I have integrated `OpenDJ` with `OpenAM`. The users created in `OpenDJ` are reflected in `OpenAM` and are able to log into `OpenAM`. I used `SHA-1` as password storage scheme in `OpenDJ`. `OpenDJ` also imports users from Liferay which also has `SHA-1` password storage scheme. The problem is that i cannot log into OpenAM. The login is failed. 
Why the users created in `OpenDJ` can log into `OpenAM` but not the users imported from Liferay although the users are reflected in OpenAM also? How to fix this?

Comment: Hi Nebula, Can you share your experience of this experiment in a blog e.t.c... Also what kind of system configuration you recommend for Open AM and Open DJ and what kind of growth you have seen after deployment(checking if micro/small instances will be good enough for these deployments)

Answer (score 1):

You may check OpenAM auth module debug log .. not sure which auth module you use.

If you use LDAP auth module then OpenAM performs an LDAP 'BIND'-operation. The password is compared on the server side, not the client (OpenAM) side. BTW the password is sent in clear text from OpenAM to OpenDJ.

-Bernhard

Comment: I am using LDAP auth module. The password is hashed as `SHA-1` in OpenDJ. I am just confused that the users created in OpenDJ can log in but not the users imported from `Liferay` to `OpenDJ` even though the users are reflected in `OpenAM`.

Comment: You verify that passwords with SHA-1 imported from Liferay can be processed by OpenDJ. OpenDJ delivers an "encode-password" tool that could be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the help provided by Ludovic and Bernhard, it seems Liferay is not creating a password in OpenDJ, as my new users wind up with an entry of:

> userPassword: {NONE}null

This seems to be a [bug](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29364) with version 6.1.  Said to be fixed in 6.2 pre-release.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to check what Liferay writes to OpenDJ using a sniffer. The default
ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm is NONE, which has the funny effect of
creating passwords with the {NONE} algorithm in OpenDJ, and apparnetly OpenDJ
does not like these. You may try adding

```
ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SHA1
```

to your Liferay portal-ext.properties file.